# android sql how to handle large Query 200000 lines database?

Tags: android, sqlite

i use this code to give suggestions to the user when typing. but one query takes lot of time. is there a way to speed up?

```
    String cnql = "SELECT DISTINCT sinhala FROM jgd WHERE sinhala LIKE '"+gg+"%'   LIMIT 0,4";   
        Cursor   cg=cn.rawQuery(cnql, null);
```

Comment: Index AT LEAST the `sinala` field. Speed boost up to a few hundred times.

Comment: @Funkystein LIKE requires TEXT affinity and a COLLATE NOCASE index.

Comment: @CL True, TEXT affinity required (and please note the TEXT affinity here: `'"+gg+"%'`). The case insensitivity is implicit within the Like, in SQLite. Nontheless, indexing the WHERE field should improve the query speed.

Comment: @Funkystein LIKE will not use an index without the correct collation.

Comment: how to Index  please tell me?

Comment: Nice tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm

Comment: i just created a index CREATE INDEX `sin` ON `jgd` (`sinhala` ASC) but dont know how to access it

Comment: Forget it. Just use the normal query without worrying about. Now it's **much faster**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [virtual table for full text searching](http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html) on Android which provides a very quick way to retrieve matching strings. However, it does require you set up and maintain a separate FTS virtual table and populate it with the strings you want to search. As its focus is full text search, it does not support a 'starts with' type of operator, although you can `gg + "*"` to search for words prefixed with your search query.